Как подключиться к Outline VPN через код?
Имеется сервер VPN на Outline, как мне подключиться к нему используя код ? Язык программирования не важен. Главное сделать VPN соединение между устройством и сервером. Все клиенты которые есть не подходят. Устройство на Linux (cli) как и сервер
